# knockout js bootstrap datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

i know this question is asked lot of times before... but i have tried all the solutions and none of them are working.... hence asking again...

how do i bind the json date to knockout element... below is the code i have...

@Html.Bootstrap().ControlGroup().TextBoxFor(x => x.DateOfBirth).HtmlAttributes(new { data_bind = "kodate: DateOfBirth, datepickerOptions : new Date()", @class = "datepicker" })

```
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true
        });
    });

    <input data-bind="kodate: startdate" class="datepicker"/>
```

the kodate is defined as below

```
ko.bindingHandlers.kodate = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    //initialize datepicker with some optional options
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
    $(element).datepicker(options);

    //when a user changes the date, update the view model
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "changeDate", function (event) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
            value(event.date);
        }
    });

    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
            value(new Date(element.value));
        }
    });

},

update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var widget = $(element).data("datepicker");
    //when the view model is updated, update the widget
    if (widget) {
        widget.date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if (!widget.date) {
            return;
        }

        if (_.isString(widget.date)) {
            widget.date = new Date(parseInt(widget.date.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
            //widget.date = new Date(widget.date);
        }

        widget.setValue();
    }
},

update_old: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

    //handle date data coming via json from Microsoft
    if (String(value).indexOf('/Date(') == 0) {
        value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
    }

    $(element).datepicker("setValue", value);
}
};
```

now the date is being displayed correctly... but when i post the date... it is posted in json format and the model binder is not able to convert the json date (/Date(1339230900000)/) to the actual date and hence the date remains null on server side...

how do make sure that the model binder converts the json date /Date(1339230900000)/ to the server side DateTime or how to post the date in different format so that model binder is able to recognize the date??

interesting thing is if i change the date, then its posted in ISO format, but if i don't change the date then its posted in json format... so may be something wrong with the init code...

i am using bootstrap-datepicker: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using a client-side library such as Moment.js to format your date properly while maintaining the two-way data-binding offered by Knockout.  A simple way to get started is using a lightweight plug-in like shown here - http://makingsense.github.io/moment-datepicker/

You are not required to use that plug-in though, you just need to write your own custom binding handler to handle getting and setting the date.  An example of this that I have used in the past -

Register a binding handler to format the date to bind to -

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $(element).datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if (String(value).indexOf('/Date(') == 0) {
            value = new Date(parseInt(value.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
        }

        var current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

And then the mark-up -

```
<div class="span4">
    <label>Start Date : </label><input data-bind="datepicker: startDate, datepickerOptions: { maxDate: new Date() }" />
</div>
```

**Note:** This answer was derived from an aggregation of other answers.